# method distanceTo(double) is undefined

Tags: android, object, locationmanager

I have a Problem to get the right way to get the distanceTo from my 2 Geo Points. How to get it work?

from the gps class:

```
double latitude; // latitude
String mlat;

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    mlat = String.valueOf(latitude);
```

from the ListView:

```
                        // Get distance
                        String mReportA;
                        double mLocB;
                        int distance;
                        mReportA = e.getString("lat");
                        mReportA = e.getString("lon");
                        mLocB = gps.latitude;
                        mLocB = gps.longitude;
                        distance = mReportA.distanceTo(mLocB);
```

Error in Eclipse: The method `distanceTo(double)` is undefined for the type String
I get `e.getString("lat");` from json

Comment: mReportA is String . distanceTo is defined for Location objects.

Comment: yes, e.getString("lat"); is from json. so it is a string. How to convert it, that it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate distance between two geopoint you can follow the below example.

```
double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

double endLatitude = lat;
double endLongitude = lng;

float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,endLatitude, endLongitude, results);

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(results[0]);// results in meters
BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
double values = rounded.doubleValue();
```

**EDIT**

```
if (values > 1000) {
 values = (Double) (values * 0.001f);// convert meters to Kilometers
 bd = new BigDecimal(values);
 rounded = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
 values = rounded.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: how can I get the result in km?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Here is the code to find out the distance between two locations 

float distance;
Location locationA = new Location("A");  

locationA.setLatitude(latA);  
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);  

Location locationB = new Location("B");  

locationB.setLatitude(latB);  
LocationB.setLongitude(lngB);  

distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

Comment: I get this e.getString("lat"); from json. so it is a string. How to convert it, that it work?

Comment: You can get the latitute and longitude for the Location A and Location B . Now you have to create two Location objects . One for A and one for B . Then You can use distanceTo function.